# Drawing on Nexus 10 to Windows 8.1

Tags: applications, windows

I have a Google / Samsung Nexus 10 Android tablet, and a Windows 8.1 laptop (Dell Latitude E6430). I'd like to use my Android tablet as a drawing surface, to draw images on my Windows laptop. The ultimate goal is to be able to make narrated videos that consist of drawings, so I would be using my laptop to record the screen, while I'm drawing from the Android tablet.

- I do not want to install anything new on my laptop (preferably)
- I need to be able to view the drawing on my laptop while I am in the process of drawing (Remote Desktop isn't an option, for this reason)

What options are there for this scenario?

[image: Drawing]

Comment: Ok, these may be silly points so bear with me. AFAIK you'll need something installed on the laptop to let the two communicate in the way you want (I could be wrong). Why can't you screen record on the tablet and bypass the whole PC thing in the first place?

Comment: @RossC: They are not silly points. What would I use to do screen recording on the tablet? I guess that could be an option, but I already have a process for recording the screen on my laptop. I am open to installing something, if absolutely necessary, but would prefer not to, if possible.

Comment: Kitkat supports screen recording, I'm on custom ROM so it's an option on my notification bar! However, here is a how to http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57610905-285/how-to-record-your-screen-on-android-4.4-kitkat/  (I think only over ADB at the moment) And here's an alternative video: http://www.geek.com/android/how-to-use-screen-recording-in-android-4-4-1576505/

Comment: @RossC: Cool, thanks. I will check that out. It doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for, but still useful.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think it was ideal, no doubt there's a better solution. I tend to think in terms of 'I'll just do it on the device'. It might just be handier for now, but going forward a better solution will be needed I guess. I'll keep at it! Something LIKE this (and there's a free trial) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.j03.mobileinput is the only bridge I can think of. It's still not what you want exactly though.

Comment: You may want to check out the several answers to [this highly relevant question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/use-an-android-tablet-as-a-wacom-drawing-tablet-for-a-pc).

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer may be an option. You can remote into your tablet using teamviewer on your laptop, to the teamviewer app on your N10. This is the only option I can think of. This would not however allow to directly circle say an icon on your desktop, for that you would need some sort of overlay application for your laptop.