# Using a stylus on my Android device

Tags: stylus

Is there any way to use a stylus with an Android device like Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo or HCL Me U1 Tablets?

Comment: Any capacitive stylus will work with a capacitive touchscren (though not a resistive one). There's really nothing OS-specific to the way they function. Are you trying to do something specific with it, though? Particular functions might be software-driven.

Comment: I see this thread and thought it would be cool if I had a stylus too. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/use-an-android-tablet-as-a-wacom-drawing-tablet-for-a-pc

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, yes. I can't see any problem using stylus on Android devices. But you need the one for capacitive screen (or "Capacitive stylus", as mentioned by [eldarerathis](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/90126/using-a-stylus-on-my-android-device/90130#comment113347_90126))

As a proof, there is [an article that lists some of the best styli for tablet devices](http://lifehacker.com/five-best-tablet-styli-1625795090).

**Disclaimer**: I'm not affiliated with the site or its creator. The site is used only as a proof that there are styli for Android tablet.