# Can Android Tablet can work on Windows 10 like Wacom Tablets?

Tags: tablet

Wacom Tablets are very expensive. I cannot afford it. I have right now Samsung Tab S6 Lite. I usually draw in Ibis Paint X with S Pen. I want to use different apps like Paint Tool SAI as it is not available in Android and I am bored working with the Ibis Paint. Can Samsung tablets change like Wacom tablet in the way that it connects to the laptop and I can use my tablet for this?! If anyone knows about the process please Can you tell me how to connect and which cable wire I have to connect with?
I hope you reply me because I HAVE THIS CRAZY WISH

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! May I recommend our site-search? For your specific question, [here are the corresponding answered questions](/search?q=wacom+answers%3A1). Most relevant: [How to turn my android to a wacom tablet?](/q/165712/16575) and [Use an Android tablet as a Wacom drawing tablet for a PC?](/q/40934/16575)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use an Android tablet as a Wacom drawing tablet for a PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/use-an-android-tablet-as-a-wacom-drawing-tablet-for-a-pc)